# ¿Por que no puedo crear un ArrayList sin parametros?

Tags: java

Me pone que el constructor no tiene parametros cuando en la API 7 java se puede construir un ArrayList sin paramentros es decir vacio.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayList {




public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create list
        List<String> crunchifyList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // add 4 different values to list
        crunchifyList.add("eBay");
        crunchifyList.add("Paypal");
        crunchifyList.add("Google");
        crunchifyList.add("Yahoo");

        // iterate via "for loop"
        System.out.println("==> For Loop Example.");
        for (int i = 0; i < crunchifyList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(crunchifyList.get(i));
        }

        // iterate via "New way to loop"
        System.out.println("\n==> Advance For Loop Example..");
        for (String temp : crunchifyList) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

        // iterate via "iterator loop"
        System.out.println("\n==> Iterator Example...");
        Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = crunchifyList.iterator();
        while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(crunchifyIterator.next());
        }

        // iterate via "while loop"
        System.out.println("\n==> While Loop Example....");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < crunchifyList.size()) {
            System.out.println(crunchifyList.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        // collection stream() util: Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source
        System.out.println("\n==> collection stream() util....");
        crunchifyList.forEach((temp) -> {
            System.out.println(temp);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: cual es el problema , que no puedes construir un arrayList sin tipo?

Comment: Me pone  que el ArrayList dont take parameters y lo quiero crear vacio

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el error?

Comment: "type Arraylist  does not take  parameters"

Comment: únicamente cambia el nombre de la clase, no uses palabras reservadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que mencionas:

> type Arraylist does not take parameters

No tiene que ver con definir un ArrayList generico o sin tipo, se debe a que tu clase tiene el nombre `ArrayList`:

```
public class ArrayList {
```

Cambia el nombre y no tendrás ningun problema, tu código es correcto, evita usar palabras reservadas.

Answer (score 2):

El problema parece ser que estás creando tu clase con el nombre ArrayList que es una clase ya existente pero que toma precedencia al ser la clase que estás creando.

Intentas instanciarla pero tu clase no tiene un constructor que reciba parámetros y te marca ese error

Tendrías que hacer una inicialización así para que funcione utilizando la clase de Java(no tu clase)

`List<String> crunchifyList = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ArrayList {
```

Has definido una clase llamada `ArrayList`. Esa es la clase `ArrayList` que usa el compilador.

Tu clase no es parametrizable, por lo que sale el error. Otra pista es que no haces `import` de `java.util.ArrayList`

Dejando aparte que el nombre es muy confuso (¿quizás tocaría renombrarla a `ArrayListTest`?), si quieres usar la clase `ArrayList` del API tendrás que usar el nombre completo (con el package):

```
List<String> crunchifyList = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Gracias, no tenía ni idea que había que usar el paquete en el constructor. En todos los ejemplos que he visto en internet no usaban el paquete

Comment: No es que haya que usar el nombre completo en el constructor. Es que si no indicas el nombre, el compilador piensa que `ArrayList` es la clase que tú has escrito, y no la del API... Como las dos clases tienen el mismo nombre "corto", tienes que usar el nombre completo para identificar correctamente la clase del API. Si cambias el nombre de tu clase, ya no necesitas poner el nombre completo para `java.util.ArrayList` (pero tienes que hacer el `import`).

Comment: En otro orden de cosas, veo que has hecho ya 13 preguntas en el sitio **y no has marcado ninguna respuesta como correcta**. Por favor, revisa el [help] para ver porqué conviene marcar las respuestas correctas (cuando lo sean).

Comment: Como marco las respuestas como correctas, perdone, no tengo mucha practica en este sitio.